# How to align the implies sign within the enumerate environment

Tags: align, enumerate

For example, how to align the implies sign here

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}} \left(\frac{x^{n+1}}        
{n+1}\right)=x^n,n\neq 1\qquad
\Rightarrow\int x^n.\mathrm{dx}=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} +\mathrm{C},n\neq 1$
\item $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}} \left(\log_e x\right)=\frac{1}  
{x}\qquad
\Rightarrow\int\frac{1}{x} .\mathrm{dx}=\log_e x+\mathrm{C}$
\end{enumerate}
```

I am unable to use `\begin{align*}` here because can't use align environment in enumerate environment. So how do I the align the implies sign in the above code?

Comment: First of all why are you using a list here? I see no reason to do so. Additionally, please provide a full minimal example instead of a sniplet. That makes testing your code much easier for us, plus det can see what kind of class and preamble you are using as that affects our answers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can use align after `\item`, but you'll have a (possibly unwanted) vertical space. If you don't want it, use the `aligned`  environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set each of the left-hand sides in a box of largest width. This process is automated via [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}`; all boxes with the same `<tag>` are fit inside a box of greatest width within that `<tag>`, with the possibility to `<align>` the content as well:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \eqmakebox[largest]{$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} 
    \Bigl( \frac{x^{n + 1}}{n + 1} \Bigr) = x^n, n \neq 1 \qquad$}%
    $\Rightarrow \int x^n\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{x^{n + 1}}{n + 1} + \mathrm{C}, n \neq 1$
  \item \eqmakebox[largest][l]{$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}
    \bigl( \log_e x \bigr) = \frac{1}{x}$}%
    $\Rightarrow \int \frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x = \log_e x + \mathrm{C}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using a canonical code (`aligned` + `\usepackage{derivative}` to obtain directly the `d` in math-roman mode).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{derivative}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item 
  $\begin{aligned}[t]
 \odv{}{x}\biggl(\frac{x^{n + 1}}{n + 1} \biggr) &= x^{n}, n \neq 1 &&&&\Rightarrow  \int x^{n} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{x^{n + 1}}{n + 1} + \mathrm{C},\,n \neq 1 
\end{aligned}$ 
\item     
$\begin{aligned}[t]
\odv{}{x}\bigl( \ln x \bigr)& =\frac{1}{x} &&&&&&&&&&\,\qquad \Rightarrow  \int \frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x = \ln x + \mathrm{C}
\end{aligned}$ 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

Assuming, that `enumerate` is not intended for equation numbers, you can use `flaign` math environment from the `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}       

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
1.  &&   \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}} \left(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right) = x^n,n\neq 1
        &   \Rightarrow \int x^n \mathrm{dx} = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} +\mathrm{C},n\neq 1  
                &&   \\
2.  &&   \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}} \left(\log_e x\right)=\frac{1}{x}
        &  \Rightarrow \int\frac{1}{x} \mathrm{dx} = \log_e x+\mathrm{C}
                &&   \\
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```